# AngularJS ng-repeat cannot access last element of array after slice()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have select using ng-repeat from array:

```
  <select data-ng-model='selectedTagForNew'   ng-change="selectedTagForNewChange()" >
        <option ng-value="{{tag.arrayindex}}"  data-ng-repeat="tag in tags |orderBy:'seq'">{{tag.seq}}&nbsp;{{tag.name}}&nbsp;({{tag.number}})</option>
    </select>
```

In my controller on certain action I remove selected element from the array:

```
    tags.splice($scope.selectedTagForNew,1);
    for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
            tags[i].arrayindex=i;
   }
    $scope.tags=tags;
```

The problem is that every time, after the first `slice()` the last element in the array when is selected gives `$scope.selectedTagForNew` as `undefined`. And as result `tags[$scope.selectedTagForNew]` is `null` object Even if it is shown in the list.
What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE: After many tests it seems that ng-repeat is not updated and so gives old values of model (`tag.arrayindex`)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code? jsfiddle/plunkr?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29844/ smth like this, but it don't get angular there....

Comment: I am new in this staff so some errors may be stupid

Comment: You missed some comas in tags array definition. Here is an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29846/. Get it work (so it will show us an error) and lets see what is your problem.

Comment: You don't have `tags` at scope at the moment. You also don't have function to  remove element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29848/ now it dosn't get even the first...

Comment: here it has really strange model value...in my code it works as arrayindex http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29850/

Answer (score 0):

Better way to slice

In typescript

```
const pos = this.tags.map(elem => { return tag._id; }).indexOf(tag._id);
this.tags.splice(pos, 1);
```

In JavaScript you can make an extension

```
Array.prototype.spliceObject = function (sourceToRemove) {
        //Remove the deleted entry from list
        var index = this.indexOf(sourceToRemove);
        if (index != -1) { // Make sure the value exists
            this.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
```

and try

```
tags.spliceObject(selectedrow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the $index in HTML to access the index of the array. For reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

And instead of using ng-repeat on options tag you can use the ng-options directive provided by angular. Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: the problem is not in ng-repeat but splice() as only after delete of first element everything explodes

Comment: $index doesn't work as ordered arrays change indexes within array

Comment: Use value instead of ng-value in options.
`<option value="{{tag.arrayindex}}"  data-ng-repeat="tag in tags |orderBy:'seq'">`